# StackOverflowException with interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hello I'm somewhat new to the world of programming.
So I tried creating an interface for a test object. As soon as I create the object I get a StackOverflowException.

Program.cs

```
class Program {

    static void Main (string[] args) {
        TestObject test = new TestObject("test");
    }

}
```

TestObject.cs

```
public class TestObject : IObject {

    public string Name {get{return Name;}set{Name = value;}}

    public TestObject (string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}

interface IObject {
    string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the interface, but the implementation of the property:

```
public string Name {get{return Name;}set{Name = value;}}
```

This is a recursive property (calls itself indefinitely) and that's what causes the StackOverflowException.

You should define your property like so (and read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)):

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Or, if you need to use a backing field:

```
public class TestObject : IObject {

    private string _name;

    public string Name { 
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public TestObject (string name) {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: most people usually have private string _name
Name can then get and set this variable if the auto getter/setter isn't enough

Comment: @w0lf - I'd change the name of `name` to `_name`

Comment: @GiladGreen Good point. I've edited the answer.

Comment: `Name = _name` should be `Name = name` without the underscore

Comment: @croxy Right! Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @w0lf Thanks for the help! Appreciate it!